# Are database options backed up in a full backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Are database options backed up in a full backup?

For instance, I have a database which has `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS` disabled (0) (AFAIK, default is 1).
When I restore a full backup of that database, does this option stay disabled(0)?

Can you point me to any reference that mentions that?

Comment: What happens when you backup and restore it?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik: options seems to be restored as backed up, but what I'm looking for it is a reference that explicitly explains that use case.

Comment: Sorry -- that's not really the question you asked, and I'm not following your follow up comment. Use case for what?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear... What I want to know is: does my database backup contain database's options, and where I can find a doc that mention this? When I check the backup Header, I see, for instance, the `READ_ONLY` state of my DB but not the `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS`

Comment: Okay, you should update your question to add more information. That's much different from what you posted.

Answer (score 2):

db options gets restored except the ones like service broker, cdc, as mentioned [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) which you have to explicitly tell when restoring the db.

I tested the autoupdate stats - setting it to false, backing up db and restoring it as different name.

For new db, you can just set the model db settings and it will get inherited.